# How to scrape items separately while multithreading?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm really new to multithreading (as in, I started learning it tonight) and I just wrote a scraper that I made multithreaded. But it just scrapes the same data twice on both threads instead of scraping it separately which is the reason I'm making it multithreaded (for time efficiency

For example, if I'm scraping:

```
1  
2  
3  
4  
5  
6  
7  
8
```

and I set the program to use 2 threads, the output is something like:

```
1  
2  
1  
2  
3  
3  
4  
5  
5  
4  
6  
7  
6  
8  
7  
8
```

Basically, instead of multiple threads scraping a list of numbers faster, it scrapes the whole list once for each thread which results in duplicates in the output (and I'm pretty sure the same scraping speed)

Sorry if any of this isn't clear or sounds dumb or something, I'm really new to multithreading like I said. I'll clear anything up if I was unclear in my post

Comment: To get help, it's best to demonstrate your issue with a piece of code. Otherwise, it's almost always too imprecise to answer.

Comment: Well, show us how you divide up the work between the two threads! How do you tell thread #1 to go for sites 1-4, and thread #2 to handle sites 5-8 ??

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Parallel`-class.
Take a look at this: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537608(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537608%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Parallel.ForEach(yourList, (listItem) =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine(listItem);
});
```

For more details take a look at the site, I've posted above.

Answer (score 0):

One general way would be to use a [job pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern), where you have your main thread providing the data to the worker threads, who then just works on the data it gets. Therefore you do not have any duplication. You do not really use multi threading, you just basically do everything twice.

There may be other ways depending on you specific problem, like two threads who only do every 2nd item, or something similar.